# How can we use DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer with RetryTemplate?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I wanted to use the RetryTemplate with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.

How can I used so that it will read the retry count and retryInterval from RetryTemplate and after retry it will move to dlq.

```java
    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(){
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(retryMaxAttempts);
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryInterval);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTM) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTM);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), 1));
        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the recovery (publishing) in the retry logic rather than in the error handler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846940/stateful-retry-with-deadletterpublishingrecoverer-causing-retrycachecapacityexce/56853046#56853046).

```java
        factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
            recoverer.accept((ConsumerRecord<?, ?>) context.getAttribute("record"),
                    (Exception) context.getLastThrowable());
            return null;
        });
```

Where `recoverer` is the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Create an instance with the provided template and destination resolving function,
 * that receives the failed consumer record and the exception and returns a
 * {@link TopicPartition}. If the partition in the {@link TopicPartition} is less than
 * 0, no partition is set when publishing to the topic.
 * @param template the {@link KafkaTemplate} to use for publishing.
 * @param destinationResolver the resolving function.
 */
public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(KafkaTemplate<? extends Object, ? extends Object> template,
        BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition> destinationResolver) {
    this(Collections.singletonMap(Object.class, template), destinationResolver);
}
```

If the DLT doesn't have as many partitions as the original topic, you need a custom destination resolver:

```
(record, exception) -> new TopicPartition("my.DLT", -1)
```

With a negative partition, Kafka will choose the partition;  the default resolver uses the same partition.

```
DEFAULT_DESTINATION_RESOLVER = (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic() + ".DLT", cr.partition());
```

This is explained in [the documentation[(https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters)

> You can also, optionally, configure it with a `BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition>`, which is called to resolve the destination topic and partition. By default, the dead-letter record is sent to a topic named `<originalTopic>.DLT` (the original topic name suffixed with .DLT) and to the **same partition as the original record**. Therefore, when you use the default resolver, the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the original topic. If the returned `TopicPartition` has a negative partition, the partition is not set in the `ProducerRecord`, so the partition is selected by Kafka.

Comment: This working for Topic partition is 0. If the topic partition is not 0 then the DLT is not logging the message. For Example: It the failed topic is having Partition 0 it is going to the 0th partition of the DLT, but if the failed topic partition is 3 it is neither showing the new partition nor the message is logging in .DLT topic.

Comment: Does your DLT have as many partitions as the main topic? If not, you need a custom topic resolver. By default, we send the failed record to the same partition as the original record. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Russel - I have created the same number of partitions for DLT also. It is logging also, but the problem is it logging same message again and again.

Comment: You should ask a new question with more details (configuration and logs).